# How to secure memcached server

Tags: linux

I have installed memcached server.
It has options in which we can specify few options.

```
options="-l 127.0.0.1"
options="-l server_ip_address"
```

Which is the best method?
Is there any other way to secure it?
I have httpd and nginx servers installed

Comment: Is there anything wrong in the question to get negative vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is the loopback (that means no connection from the LAN are allowed). So it's the most secure (and best performing) way if your server is accessed only locally.

Comment: can I change the default port 11211 to something else? Or just adding 127.0.0.1 is good enough?

Comment: yeah, with `-p <port>` but if it's bound only to the loopback I think is good enough the default 11211.